# Format the SQL query to a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)    
SET @sql='SELECT DISTINCT
        WS.SIMNumber,
        SMTP.SMTPMappingId,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),WS.ExpiryDate,106) as ExpiryDate,
        CASE 
            WHEN BES.DisplayName IS NOT NULL THEN BES.DisplayName+'@'+SMTP.DomainName
            ELSE 
            CASE WHEN BES.PIN IS NOT NULL THEN BES.PIN+'@'+SMTP.DomainName 
            ELSE '' END END AS EmailId,
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ExpiringEmailSimCardSent WHERE SimNumber=WS.SIMNumber AND ExpiryDate=WS.ExpiryDate)>0
            THEN CONVERT(BIT,1)
            ELSE CONVERT(BIT,0)
            END AS IsEMailSent
    FROM   
        WEBSERVICE_CACHE AS WS   
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        BES_SERVER_CACHE  AS BES ON WS.SIMNumber = LEFT(BES.ICCID,19)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        BES_SMTP_Mapping AS SMTP ON BES.BESSqlServer = SMTP.BesServer
     WHERE 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 109) > CONVERT(DATETIME, WS.ExpiryDate, 109)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

I have this SQL query want to convert it into a `nvarchar` variable because of @ and '' . I am getting some errors
```

I am getting this errorMsg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '@'.

If I rectify that it comes for another at @ and ' '

Comment: can you show your error?

Comment: I have edited the code and put the error also

Comment: What is this meant to be doing? `BES.PIN+'@'+SMTP.DomainName`

Comment: I want to create a mail id by  concatenating two columns  as EmailId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to 'escape' your quotes:

This:

```
BES.PIN+'@'+SMTP.DomainName
```

Should be something like this:

```
BES.PIN+'''@'''+SMTP.DomainNam
```

experiment....

Comment: Correct will be with two single quotes not 3 any ways it helped :). Thanks a ton Nick